# Add options to plugin in gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, protoc

I'm using the gradle plugin 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.6.0' for generating my `.java` files from `.proto` files.

Additionally I want to generate documentation for my `.proto` files. For this I found protoc-gen-doc.exe. This works fine fomr the commandline with the following command:

```
path/to/protoc/protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-doc=path/to/docGen/protoc-gen-doc.exe --doc_out=./doc --doc_opt=html,index.html test.proto
```

In my gradle script I have the following task:

```
protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/"
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.6.0'
    }
    plugins {
        doc {
          path = 'path/to/genDoc/protoc-gen-doc.exe'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                doc {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I can pass the `--doc_out` and `--doc_opt` parameters to the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the following should work:

```
protobuf {
  ...
  generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
      task.plugins {
        doc {
          outputSubDir = 'doc'
          option 'html'
          option 'index.html'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```